# In Ethereum Solidity, when changing an array length, I get "Value must be an lvalue". Why?

Tags: ethereum

In Solidity, you can increase the size of an array to make room for a new member by using **array.length++**. But I'm getting an error:

```
Value must be an lvalue
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can resize a dynamic array in storage (i.e. an array declared at the contract level) with “arrayname.length = ;” But if you get the “lvalue” error, you are probably doing one of two things wrong.
You might be trying to resize an array in *memory*, or
You might be trying to resize a *non-dynamic* array.

```
int8[] memory somearray;     // CASE 1
somearray.length++;          // illegal 

int8[5] somearray;           // CASE 2
somearray.length++;          // illegal
```

IMPORTANT NOTE: In Solidity, arrays are declared backwards from the way you’re probably used to declaring them. And if you have a >=2D array with some dynamic and some non-dynamic components, you may violate #2 and not understand why. Note also that arrays are accessed the “normal” way. Here's are some examples of this "backward" declaration paradigm in action:

```
int8[][5] somearray;  // This is 5 dyn arrays, NOT a dyn array-of-arrays w/len=5
// so...
somearray[4];         // the last dynamic array
somearray[1][12];     // the 13th element of the second dynamic array
// thus...
somearray.length++;   // illegal. This array has length 5. Always.
somearray[0].length++;// legal
```

Comment: what if my variable length array is just temporary and should remain as memory? i can't modify the length or push a new item to it?

Answer (score 0):

Encountered same issue and what I had to was use the `storage` keyword since I was trying to modify a global storage array.

```
bytes32[] storage someArray = someGlobalStorageArray;
```